# autosubmit form doing that to the same page instead of action url

Tags: javascript

I bumped with strange issue. When I submit for with javascript it makes submit to the same page instead of action url.
I open form url  `somemyurl`

```
    <form id='theForm' action='https://help.ontherurl.com/hr/admin/ticket/store/step1' method='POST' >
    <input type='hidden' name='user' value='17'>
    <input type='hidden' name='brand' value='1'>
    <input type='hidden' name='department' value='1'>
    <input type='hidden' name='internal' value='0'>

    </form>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
    console.log(document.getElementById('theForm').action)
    document.getElementById('theForm').submit();
    </script>
```

and when page loaded it just reloading `somemyurl` endless instead of submit to https://help.ontherurl.com...

Comment: what does the `console.log` show ?
did you try to wait for the `DOM` to load before submitting ?

Comment: @UriGoren it shows url where it suppose redirect. I even added submit button and if press submit the form goes to the same url instead action url.